# jQuery off('click').on('click') dirty-fix or legit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this solution to fix my `.on('click')` fires multiple times problem. What I'd like to know as a newbie is if this is a clean way to solve the problem or just a quick/dirty-fix and how to solve it properly.

I can provide code-snippets if really needed, but a general answer would be enough

EDIT:
HTML-implementation:

```
<p class="select2-style-button-100-center">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="button-detach-profile" class="button linearize chevron-circle-left-icon">detach</a>
</p>
```

And JS-Code:

```
vm.buttonDetachProfile.off('click').click(function(e) {
    var assignedProfiles = vm.assignedProfiles.DataTable().rows('.selected').data();
    if(assignedProfiles && assignedProfiles.length > 0) {
        editProfiles('remove', assignedProfiles);
    }
    return false;
});
```

vm.buttonDetachProfile is my selector

Comment: Yes.. Code snippets might be good to provide accurate solution. But in the mean time you can capture `event` within click handler and write `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` or just `return false;`

Comment: Yes that works and is legit but really, the fact that you're assigning a handler multiple times is what you should really fix

Comment: It's a matter of opinion (and so off-topic for SO). My opinion: It's a dirty fix. The real solution is to determine why you're trying to attach handlers more than once and fix *that*.

Answer (score -1):

Code snippet to provide some context would help.

Also you can try something like this in the code to prevent multiple executions

```
clickcount++;
    if (clickcount == 1) {}
```